# Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm in Django class based view

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to create user by API view. But I get this problem:

[image]

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```

views.py

```
class UserRegistration(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should override serializer's [`create()`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) method to hash password before saving new user object. You can use [`set_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) for this:

```
 class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
            username=validated_data['username']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

Otherwise User.password will be stared in DB without hashing which is not secure.

Also you can use [`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) method which is calling `set_password` by defaut:

```
 class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'password')

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User(
        username=validated_data['username']
    )
    user.set_password(make_password(validated_data['password']))
    user.save()
    return user
```